# How to show some animation while angular compilation is in process

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compilation

I have a directive called `my-list` which takes an `array` as input data, I am using `ng-repeat` to repeat through the array and generate a list. The list is generated very slow if the `array` has many `objects` within it.

While the `DOM` elements are generated I want to show a spinner animation. But while the `DOM` elements are generated the UI is frozen.

I would like to know if there is a solution for this problem.

Comment: The solution would be to chunk the population of the array in more manageable pieces allowing the app to digest the small change before you go get another small change for it to digest. Also, if your data lives in the API, just get enough to show that there is more to show off screen and get more as user scrolls to end.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `$last` property in a directive:

**Directive:**

```
app.directive("lastItemLoaded", function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if(scope.$last) {
            scope.everythingLoaded = true;
            scope.$apply();
        }
    };
}

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.everythingLoaded = false;
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things" last-item-loaded></div>

<div id="mySpinner" ng-if="!everythingLoaded">
    Loading.  Please wait&hellip;
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply before the request you should set your controller variable false like that:
(its inoperative code just example)

```
$scope.someHttpRequestOnClick= function () {
     $scope.requestBusy = true;
     $http(request).then( onSuccess, function(response) {
        onFailure(response, failure);
       ......
      });
      ......
    };

function onSuccess(response){
 $scope.requestBusy = false;
  ....
}
```

I recommend angular-material mdProgressCircular directive for html indicator like that:

```
<div class="indicator" ng-if="requestBusy">
          <md-progress-circular class="md-warn md-hue-3" md-diameter="80"></md-progress-circular>
        </div>
```

for more info about mdProgressCircular ang angular-material

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdProgressCircular